# php 5.6 ssl certificate verify

Tags: php, ssl

I am trying to debug a problem with ssl certificate verification and have determined that openssl get cert locations with returning incorrect paths. (See below)

How do I figure out how to set this? I looked in the php.ini file and couldn't find this reference anywhere.

```
cmuench-air:bin cmuench$ ./php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
Array
(
    [default_cert_file] => /bitnami/mampstack56Dev-osx-x64/output/common/openssl/cert.pem
    [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
    [default_cert_dir] => /bitnami/mampstack56Dev-osx-x64/output/common/openssl/certs
    [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
    [default_private_dir] => /bitnami/mampstack56Dev-osx-x64/output/common/openssl/private
    [default_default_cert_area] => /bitnami/mampstack56Dev-osx-x64/output/common/openssl
    [ini_cafile] => 
    [ini_capath] => 
)
```

php.ini (relevant parts)...I don't see bitnami/mampstack56Dev anywhere...

```
[openssl]
; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may still
; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
; option.
;openssl.cafile=

; If openssl.cafile is not specified or if the CA file is not found, the
; directory pointed to by openssl.capath is searched for a suitable
; certificate. This value must be a correctly hashed certificate directory.
; Most users should not specify a value for this directive as PHP will
; attempt to use the OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified,
; this value may still be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "capath"
; SSL stream context option.
;openssl.capath=

;Curl ca bundle certificate
curl.cainfo="/Applications/phppos/common/openssl/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

EDIT:

I know this is dumb but there are times where the ssl certificate will be self signed. Is there an ini setting I can modify to disable checking all certificates? or do I have to do this in code for sockets and curl?

Comment: Those bitnami/mampstack paths are the OS managed paths being returned by calling the native OpenSSL functions.  Those default paths are defined based on the OpenSSL install path: see http://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/openssl/1.0.1c/cryptlib_8h.html#a632c06aa262d7c398d82f89f50f636bf  You probably need to manually code the path into your scripts to look for the proper certs or put them in that directory.

Comment: So are those paths hardcoded in a binary file somewhere that I can't really get at?

Comment: They end up being hardcoded since they are compiled into OpenSSL based on its configuration options used when the software is configured and compiled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you check the PHP source for the [`openssl_get_cert_locations()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/openssl/openssl.c#1306) function, it is getting those locations by calling various OpenSSL functions such as [`X509_get_default_cert_file`](http://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/openssl/1.0.1c/crypto_2x509_2x509_8h.html#a81698e7131828dd779b28067287f7a80) and looking at `php.ini` values `openssl.cafile` and `openssl.capath` described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php).

What certificates/paths are you looking for exactly?  If you are trying to get a CA bundle file you could set the above referenced `php.ini` values so they are returned by `openssl_get_cert_locations`.

The default `php.ini` file for PHP 5.6 has no default settings for those OpenSSL ini settings as they need to be defined manually.  This configuration is located near the end of `php.ini`

```
[openssl]
; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may still
; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
; option.
;openssl.cafile=

; If openssl.cafile is not specified or if the CA file is not found, the
; directory pointed to by openssl.capath is searched for a suitable
; certificate. This value must be a correctly hashed certificate directory.
; Most users should not specify a value for this directive as PHP will
; attempt to use the OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified,
; this value may still be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "capath"
; SSL stream context option.
;openssl.capath=
```

When using cURL, you can use the option `CURLOPT_CAINFO` to provide the full path to the file holding one or more certificates to verify the peer with by using [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt):

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/ca/bundle");
```

This can also be set in `php.ini`:

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
;curl.cainfo =
```

Comment: I am just trying to get valid paths and cannot find it. I will update my question with my php.ini once I look for those settings.

Comment: I posted my php.ini with that part

Comment: Also what is the difference between ca file and ca path? What is ca info? and where is default_cert_dir coming from (The path)

Comment: Just commented on your OP.  The CA file is the path to the CA file, the path is just a search path (directory) for CA files based on a name.  Those default paths are coming from OpenSSL based on its installation directory.  If you place your certs in that folder PHP will pick them up based on those values

Comment: Thanks! One final question. is there a way to disable all verificative of certs for curl and sockets? Or do I have to pass a variable to each function?

Comment: @ChrisMuench For CURL just add these 2 lines in php:`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` if you mean from php.ini I have no idea

Comment: @Mihai do you know how to disable for socket? `fsockopen($ssl.$this->smtp_host, $this->smtp_port,$errno,$errstr,$this->smtp_timeout);`

Comment: Just added the option for disabling cert checks for cURL.  You can also disable them with sockets using `stream_context_create` or `stream_context_set_params` and the `ssl` option `verify_peer => false`

Comment: @ChrisMuench Just updated the answer with the option to disable checking for fsockopen as well as curl.

Comment: @drew010 I got error Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Comment: @ChrisMuench Hi Chris, sorry about that - updated the answer to use stream_socket_client which is similar to fsockopen but supports a context prior to establishing the stream.

Comment: Thanks @drew010 my only question is that I am modifying a core library. Is this a drop in replacement? Will the other socket functions work? (It works in this case but what about TLS and non ssl). I am modifying https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2-stable/system/libraries/Email.php line 1686

Comment: @ChrisMuench That stream function is a drop in replacement for fsockopen, it returns the same type of resource just gives you more control over the connection and parameters.  The SSL option also applies to TLS connections and if you are not using SSL/TLS then it won't have any effect (or you could get fancy and call normal fsockopen for non ssl/tls connections and stream_socket_client for ssl/tls connections).

Comment: And one final question. Is `stream_socket_client` guaranteed to be installed on all php 5.2 and greater (Along with other commands). On the manual it says php 5; but doesn't have a version.

Comment: @ChrisMuench Yes stream_socket_client is a standard PHP stream function like fsockopen available in all versions of PHP5 so no special extensions are required to have it.

Comment: @drew010 You should add a note to your answer that disabling CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER etc will enable man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. default_cert_dir shows a very old cert dir that doesn't exist anymore, and a web search shows no way to change the cert dir in openssl. Yes, I did reinstall openssl, but it did not ask me for any directory paths.