# PHP 5.6 openssl change cert. path

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, php-5.6

I'm opening a connection like this:

```
fsockopen('ssl:// ... etc
```

Which returns with the following error:

> Warning: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I'm probably getting this error because I'm upgrading from *PHP 5.3* to *PHP 5.6*, in *PHP 5.6* they actually check your certificate.

I checked my certs location with:

```
openssl_get_cert_locations()
```

Which returned the following:

```
Array
(
   [default_cert_file] => f:\repo\winlibs_openssl_vc11_x86/cert.pem
   [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
   [default_cert_dir] => f:\repo\winlibs_openssl_vc11_x86/certs
   [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
   [default_private_dir] => f:\repo\winlibs_openssl_vc11_x86/private
   [default_default_cert_area] => f:\repo\winlibs_openssl_vc11_x86
   [ini_cafile] => 
   [ini_capath] => C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\PEM\cert.pem
)
```

The bad part is, I do not even have a '`f:\`' location! 
I tried to fix this by adding the ini_capath location in my `php.ini` like so:

```
 openssl.capath=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\PEM\cert.pem
```

Which you can see in the array provided by `get_cert_location`

I'm pretty clueless why its going to the `F:` disk (like I said, I do not even have that one), and I also do not know how to change the location.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php 5.6 ssl certificate verify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460941/php-5-6-ssl-certificate-verify)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I've reinstalled openssl, but the openssl certificate directory is still wrong.