# Setting OpenSSL to be false in verify_peer and verify_peer_name

Tags: codeigniter-3, php-5.6, php-openssl

i need for help. I got many documentations that told about PHP 5.6 must be manually set to openSSL feature. It said that "to disable peer certificate verification for a request by setting the verify_peer context option to FALSE, and to disable peer name validation by setting the verify_peer_name context option to FALSE". But i don't know where and how to apply those settings. I'm using PHP CodeIgniter 3 and want to sending email but get error in fsockopen(). Could you please help me? Thank you for your answers, I appreciate it :D

Comment: Check out this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460941/php-5-6-ssl-certificate-verify]here.

Answer (score 2):

in php 5.6 > the default value for verify_peer= true, you need to change the context

```
$remote = "ssl://smtp.xxxx.de:465";
$errorNum = "";
$errorStr = "";
$context = stream_context_create(array(
                    'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer'      => false,
                        ), 
                    )
                );

$socket = stream_socket_client($remote, $errorNum, $errorStr, 30, null, $context);
```