# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host in php

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

On sending emails from Gmail through SMTP I got this error:

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

I tried:

```
require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
$mail->Port       = 465;             
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Username="mail@gmail.com";  
$mail->Password="password";            
$mail->SetFrom('mail@gmail.com','Store');
$mail->AddReplyTo("mail@gmail.com","Store");
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->Send();
```

**Gmail account setting for "Less secure apps" is `turned on`**

**Update:**

After trying this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48287431/8860740), I am getting:

> Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\wamp64\www\project\mailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1522

Comment: check your gmail account setting for "Less secure apps". You will need to enable this setting for sending mail from php

Comment: @Tarun It's enabled

Comment: if enable "Less secure apps" doesn't help then set $mail->SMTPDebug to 2 or 4 which will give your debug and you can trace the exact problem.

Comment: try the below settings. 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Port = 587;

Comment: @Tarun on debug to 2 it says, `SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)`

Comment: Check the code in my answer.. and test if it works for you. I had the same problem few days ago and i had to set SMTP options for ssl.

Comment: No you don't need to set "use less secure apps", nor should you disable certificate verification: it's unsafe. All of these things are covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). You most likely have outdated CA certificates, which has been covered on here and in the docs many times before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL3\_GET\_SERVER\_CERTIFICATE certificate verify failed on Windows 10 Pro with IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129318/ssl3-get-server-certificate-certificate-verify-failed-on-windows-10-pro-with-iis)

Answer (score -1):

I am using below code for setting my values.. and it is working fine for me.

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isSMTP();
        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (for production use)
        // 1 = client messages
        // 2 = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "mail@gmail.com";
        //Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password = "password";

        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );

        $mail->setFrom("mail@gmail.com",$from);
        $mail->addAddress("mail@gmail.com");
        //Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = "subject";
        $mail->Body = "body";
        $mail->send();
```

Comment: can I have a phpmailer folder you are using?

Comment: on running your code I get: `SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP b69sm6124541pfk.128 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2405:204:9122:2692:f802:cae2:3f01:6b57] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS`

Comment: Using the latest from stable branch. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable

Comment: `Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in C:\wamp64\www\...........................`

Comment: After downloading from the provided link, and running I get: `Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\wamp64\www\project\mailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1522`

Comment: check the following link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1022, setting ssl parameters in smpt option should be a fix for this problem

Comment: OK, it means the problem is occurring on running in the localhost.

Comment: @NamarsahaMNetworking for me the code is working fine on the localhost as well.

Comment: Don't tell people to disable verification - it's not a fix, it's just hiding the problem and making their systems vulnerable. Follow the link to the troubleshooting guide and do what it says.