# fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086

Tags: php, smtp, opencart, google-workspace

```
Warning: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in D:\vhosts\abc.com\httpdocs\system\library\mail.php on line 170
Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in D:\vhosts\abc.com\httpdocs\system\library\mail.php on line 170
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error) in D:\vhosts\abc.com\httpdocs\system\library\mail.php on line 170
Notice: Error: (0) in D:\vhosts\abc.com\httpdocs\system\library\mail.php on line 179
```

My client's website is unable to send out email and above are the error messages when I use SMTP.

Below are the differences between test and live environments:

1. It works on testing environment but not on the live server. The testing environment was in linux and the live server is on Windows.
2. My client's email service provider is Google G Suite.

I tried the default PHP mail() and also SMTP.

Both are unable to send mail.

Any idea what is the root cause of these issues. How do I fix it? How to avoid this kind of scenarios?

Comment: have a look at this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129318/ssl3-get-server-certificate-certificate-verify-failed-on-windows-10-pro-with-iis