# PHPMailer smtp connection failed on server

Tags: php, ssl, yii2, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer class to send an email from my website, locally its work good but on my online server I got an error:

```
2018-05-28 12:03:40 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2018-05-28 12:03:40 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [/home/beesystems/public_html/specs/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 325]
2018-05-28 12:03:40 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [/home/beesystems/public_html/specs/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 325]
2018-05-28 12:03:40 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error) [/home/beesystems/public_html/specs/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 325]
2018-05-28 12:03:40 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

code:

```
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->Port = 465;

           $mail->Username = \Yii::$app->params['mailer-account'];
           $mail->Password = \Yii::$app->params['mailer-password'];
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the code you're using?

Comment: @R.F.Nelson check the code plz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL3\_GET\_SERVER\_CERTIFICATE certificate verify failed on Windows 10 Pro with IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129318/ssl3-get-server-certificate-certificate-verify-failed-on-windows-10-pro-with-iis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the important part:

> SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

This is covered extensively in the troubleshooting guide the error message links to, and has been answered many times on here. Switching `SMTPSecure` to `tls` on port 587 won't help. It's most likely that your server is running an old version of PHP, or has an outdated CA certificates bundle.